# how to iterate every line from variable on the basis of new line character instead of space in csh

Tags: shell, csh

```
#!/bin/csh -f

foreach line (`cat test.txt`)
  echo "$line"
end
```

test.txt file contains following content :

> How to Ask
>
> Is your question about programming?
>
> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
>
> Provide details. Share your research.
>
> If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.

But on running the above **csh** **script** i am getting following output which prints on the basis of space delimiter instead of new line

```
./test.csh
```

output is in file [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this;

```
#!/bin/csh -f
foreach line ( "`cat test.txt`" )
  echo $line
end
```

Test :

```
$ csh test.csh 
How to Ask
Is your question about programming
We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.
Provide details. Share your research.
If your question is about this website, ask it on meta instead.
```

Comment: Could you please explain how it fix delimiter from space to new line.

Comment: It only works because you've removed the `?` from the second line of source text